# Changing the Header Text Style

Tags: header-footer

I want to change the text style of `header` but unfortunately, into the `packages` file I have used, I didn't find any `package` related to the `header`.

I have used the `cmr` family font style for the normal text and I would like to know, how can I also make the `header` style to`cmr` and in `italic` form? 
(See the attached figure to see the text style difference between header and the normal text)
[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass[
DIV=12,          
BCOR=5mm,  
headsepline     
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\begin{document}

\section{Model Specifications}
Specifications and the reactances of the synchronous generator are tabulated as:

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean you want the header with a sans serif font, not cmr, which has serifs?

Comment: I want the `header` with same font as that of normal text, which is a`cmr`. @Bernard

Comment: This picture is not the result of the MWE. Headers with text font in italic shape are default for `scrbook`. Maybe you load/use a package like `fancyhdr`?

Comment: Yes, the picture is from actual document that is being written in TexStudio. I had `fancyhdr` but I'm not using it any more. And I got the proper result if I test this with `Texworks`. But I want it in `TexStudio`. @esdd

Comment: Please run your MWE in a new file with TeXStudio and show as the result of the code in your question. TeXworks and TeXstudio are only editors. There should be no difference.

Comment: When I run the same above mentioned code in TexStudio, it also works fine. But if I run it with my actual main file's packages, this does not even shoe the header. I guess there is some problem in one of the `packages` I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{%
\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape\small}
```

Comment: No, it hasn't worked.

Comment: With the code you posted and nothing else?

Comment: I have tried your suggested code in `Texworks` and it has worked there. But I am writing in `Texstudio` and want to make it work here.

Comment: TeXstudio has nothing to see with this: it's just an editor. It's LaTeX which does the job, and if you have the same versions of the packages, it has to work the same way.

Comment: Both have the same compile even but I don't know I've  tried this many times, also with `PDFLatex` command but didn't get the solution.

Comment: Which version of koma-script do you have? Which distribution?

Comment: I have tried finding it but didn't find it. I'm sorry I do not know where to look for the koma-script version. @Bernard